# Why was my question moved/closed arbitrarily?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I recently posted a question I thought best suited Stack Overflow on this site. However, this question was closed and moved to Server Fault by somebody within 10 mins of my posting it.

While I can respect those guys' opinion on which site is more appropriate for my question, what annoys me was that I was not even warned or told of the move, much less given a chance to explain why I put it here. If questions keep getting moved to sister sites by arbitrary people, it is going to be very hard to keep track of all my questions.

And forget this inconvenience, isn't it just plain good manners to first notify contributors that their question might be more appropriate for another forum?

I think a better scheme would be to allow users to flag questions as more appropriate for another site and give the questioner some time to respond to it. If he/she does not answer within that period and sufficient number of users think that the question should be moved elsewhere, then move close and move it. The present system is just too chaotic. At the very least, users should be able to access all sites on StackExchange from a single account.

EDIT: Link to question: [How to prevent Linux from deleting temporary files on shutdown](https://serverfault.com/questions/147512/how-to-prevent-linux-from-deleting-temporary-files-on-shutdown).

Comment: Link to the question, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Does it matter what the question was? Will it add/subtract to the point I am trying to make here? Anyway, I have aded it to the post.

Comment: please explain how that is programming related

Comment: *migrated to serverfault.com by OMG Ponies, Robert Harvey, Neil Butterworth, Paul R, knittl 1 hour ago* -- now which one of these is "that guy"?

Comment: I guess I should have said "those guys".

Comment: *This didn't really give me a chance to explain why I posted to Stack Overflow to begin with.* Why did you post [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959586/how-to-prevent-linux-from-deleting-temporary-files-on-shutdown-closed) on SO?

Comment: Concrete examples are *very* important.  But also here on Meta, we can quickly determine if this is abuse or misunderstanding, because you deal with those very differently.  @raj

Comment: If I'm in doubt about something, I'll often wait for the OP to respond to messages.  This question is very definitely unsuitable for SO, so I'd have voted to migrate immediately.  I fail to see why an explanation would help in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think a better scheme would be to
>   allow users to flag questions as more
>   appropriate for another site and give
>   the questioner some time to respond to
>   it.

You had six minutes. :)

Unlike many other forums, where it is not uncommon to wait a day or two to get a response, things happen *very quickly* on StackOverflow.  This is by design; it helps people get rapid answers to their questions.

For this reason, it is prudent to carefully review the FAQ, and spend a few minutes thinking about whether the question is appropriate for the site, and if it is, thinking about how it should be composed *before* posting it.

Comment: "By design": That's a developer's answer :). Ironic??

Comment: No, the whole reason most of us use SO is because we don't have time to dirk around with waiting on an answer. The `intent` of the site is to get an answer in minutes. Welcome to development, where when you lose the train of thought, you've lost a half hour's useful time, might as well go take a walk in the park (you'll get Vitamin D that way!)

Answer (score 7):

You were given notice that your question was off-topic 6 minutes prior to the migration (and a scant minute after you asked the question). You didn't respond.

Five people had to vote before your question was migrated. This was hardly an arbitrary decision, much less one made by a single rogue user.

And finally, the best time to make your case for why a question belongs on SO is *when you're writing the question*. If you have to argue after the fact, chances are you did a poor job of asking in the first place...

Comment: 6 mins/1 min?? Do you think people sit and stare at the post till the first response? You call that time to respond!!

Comment: @Rajorshi: I do when I ask a question. I'm quite disappointed if I don't get an answer within three minutes.

Comment: @Rajorshi: You must assume that even if it isn't *answered* in that time, someone will probably *see* it and (if necessary) comment, close, or flag it. So you're doing yourself a disservice if you post and then *leave* - you should at least refresh after a couple of minutes in case someone *has* left a response. Otherwise, you have only yourself to blame - the site and its users did exactly what you proposed, but you yourself did not.

Comment: @Rajorshi, yeah, it's kind of a shock at first, and inconvenient sometimes, but overall, the benefits of speed far outweigh the negatives.  You asked a good question, and I hope you stick around; the system will make sense soon enough.

Answer (score 3):

To give you the benefit of the doubt, I guess you were asking how to protect the `tmp` directory **programmatically**.  But you didn't explicitly say that you wanted a program solution, and the natural first response to your kind of question is to modify a setting in some sort of operating system control panel.  Using OS settings, SF or SU would be the correct location; that's probably why the move.

Edit: I intentionally answered the question that you asked in the title, rather than the one you asked in the body, because I have nothing to add to Shog9's and Robert's answers for the latter.